# How to copy files into different directory in a remote machine

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, scp

How to copy files into different directory in a remote machine?

For Example:

- My server : 10.10.0.1
- Remote Server : 10.10.0.2

I have to login to 10.10.0.1 (*through Putty*). From here, I have to copy a file in remote machine from `/home/test/myFile.txt` to `/home/bkp/myFile.txt`.

**Both source and destination folders are in remote machine.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can `ssh` to 10.10.22.12 as "username" and "username" has write permissions to /home/testBkp:

```
scp /home/test/sample.txt username@10.10.22.12:/home/testBkp/sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use scp.  For example:

```
scp file_to_copy user@server:/home/user/foldername/filename.ext
```